# How to update the texblock string globally in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I need to update textblock inside childWindow based on file name that is being selected with OpenDialog Window. Since I am not running OpenDialog from childWindow I have trouble passing that value to the texblock inside ChildWindow. I am wondering if someone can help. As a result of th issue I have, I am wondering if it is possible to have OpenDialog inside ChildWindow? Thank you for any ideas!

ChildWindow xaml:

```
<sdk:ChildWindow 
x:Class="AddPackages_ChildWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"   
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AddPackages_ChildWindow">

<Grid x:Name="AddPackages_ChildWindow_LayoutRoot" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AddPackages_ChildWindow_LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource AVV_GridStyle}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtUpdate_Package" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="txtUpdate_Package" Text="FileName" />  </Grid>
```

Below is the code to open DialogBox and passing selected file name:

```
private void Package_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddPackage_ChildWindow ap = new AddPackage_ChildWindow();
        ap.Show();

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "App-V Packages (*.sprj)|*.sprj|App-V Packages (*.sprj)|*.sprj";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            //passing the file name string
            txtUpdate_Package.Text = openFileDialog1.File.Name;
            System.IO.Stream fileStream = openFileDialog1.File.OpenRead();

            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                // Read the first line from the file and write it the textbox.
                // txtUpdate_Package.Text = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expose a SetText method on your ChildWindow class like so:

```
public void SetText(string text) {
    this.txtUpdate_Package.Text = text;
}
```

Then you'd call it like so from your Package_Click method:

```
ap.SetText(reader.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too concerned with what the the OO purists think you can change this line in your code:-

```
txtUpdate_Package.Text = openFileDialog1.File.Name;
```

to this:-

```
ap.txtUpdate_Package.Text = openFileDialog1.File.Name;
```

This works because the auto-generated class file created for your child window Xaml will have a field of type `TextBlock` called `txtUpdate_Package` with the access of internal, i.e.

```
internal TextBlock txUpdate_Package;
```

This field is is assigned during the ChildWindow's InitializeComponent method called as part of its constructor.

However, I would prefer to create a public property to be used to handle this rather than write code the relies on what should be considered the private internal structure.  Add this property to the Code behind of your child window.

```
public string Text
{
     get { return txtUpdate_Package.Text; }
     set { txtUpdate_Package.Text = value; }
}
```